# Page reloads after form submission using ng-submit or ng-click, Changing button types is also not working

Tags: html, angularjs

I have made a form and I need to submit the form but whenever I tried to do the same the page reloads and does nothing! I tried both ng-submit `<form>` attribute and the ng-click as a `<button>` attribute! I also tried changing the button type from "submit" to "button" then also I get the same result!

Any help would be seriously appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: what is `action` and `method` set in form element ? and please [add minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: There is no "action" and "method" set in my form element!

Comment: Can you add your code here please, or create a jsfiddle.

Comment: @DhruvShrivastava if you have any `a` tags with href attribute set to anything other than a route, this will happen, are there any? if there are give them href attribute as without any value (E.g:  `<a href></a>`)

Comment: @NarenMurali No there are no "a" tags in my code and the ones which are there all have the "href" set to a route only!

Answer (score 0):

hope this simple plunker example helps 
https://plnkr.co/edit/5q9149KSs7qJH0R32NAS?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">

<form ng-submit="myFunc()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<p>{{submited}}</p>

<script>
var app = angular.module("App", []);
app.controller("Ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.submited = [];
    $scope.myFunc = function () {
        $scope.submited.push($scope.data);
    }
});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```